# How to get a value from specific key

Tags: python, python-3.x

I defined a class like that:

```
class NodeData :
    key = 0
    neighbors = {}
    location = ()

    def __init__(self, k, l):
        self.key = k
        self.location = l
        self.neighbors = {k: {}}

    def __str__(self) :
        return "key = %d" % self.key + ", pos = " + '{0}'.format(self.location) +\
               ", neighbors = " + '{0}'.format(NodeData.neighbors.get(self.key))
```

and now I need to connect edges between those nodes with weight.
So, I created a dictionary in dictionary like that:

```
node = NodeData(1, (5, 0, 0))
node.neighbors = {0: 1.2}
```

So, neighbors has this now:

```
{1: {0: 1.2}}
```

Then, I created another node:

```
node2 = NodeData(2, (6, 0, 0))
```

Now, I want to connect `node2` to `node` but I have struggle with how to know if `node2.key` is already a neighbor of `node`

This function gets the neighbor of node:
`NodeData.neighbors.get(node.key)` but I didn't find a way to compare it with node2.key

node2 returns `key = 2, pos = (6, 0, 0), neighbors = None` so it doesn't match `NodeData.neighbors.get(node.key)`

Already tried `NodeData.neighbors.get(node.key).get(node2.key)` but it returns:

`'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'`

Beacuse `node2` is not a neighbor of `node`

Any advice?

Comment: Can you clarify what type of data structure you are trying to implement? Is it some sort of tree?

Comment: How did you go from `node.neighbors = {0: 1.2}` to _"neighbors is now `{1: {0: 1.2}}`"_?

Comment: I'm trying to implement a graph.

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that `neighbors = {}` defines a class attribute and `self.neighbors = {k: {}}` an instance attribute? They are not the same.

Comment: @zvone First, I built a new Nodedata with the `key = 1` and then I entered  neighbors dictionary the values `{0: 1.2}`

Comment: If you're trying to implement a graph, then why are you not using an available graph package?  You didn't label this as homework.

Comment: @zvone so how should I define `neighbors` in the first place?

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
Don't leave us to stitch your code together into a valid example, or to insert tracing `print` statements for you.  Also, where are you not understand the many implementations of graph classes available on line?

Comment: @Prune It is pretty much what I wrote. The only thing I didnt write is the function I try to write which is `add_edge` - I just want to connect an edge between two nodes. nothing too hard. The only question I have actually is how to get the value of a key in dictionary inside a dictionary. There is no answer in the internet about that.

Comment: I succeed in adding an edge between them but I want to forbid the option of overwrite over an edge that has already been added. This is the IF statement I don't know how to write.

Comment: In the last line of the code, is your use of `NodeData.neighbors.get(self.key)` voluntary? Or did you mean `self.neighbors.get(self.key)`?

Answer (score 0):

Use the `[]` syntax to access nested values.

For example

```
dic = { "key" : {"key 2" : 20} }

dic["key"]["key 2"]
```

Which will return

```
20
```

Comment: Actually I tried that. But, it doesn't work because - When I do it with IF like that: `if dic.get("key").get("key 2")` then I get a NULL error because `key 2` doesn't exist

Comment: Hey @John I edited my answer to use `[]` syntax instead of the `.get()` method . That should work better